# git cherry-pick file conflicts and I would like to use the one in head

Tags: git

Current branch, `dev`, has a `HEAD` commit `Cdev`, and I `cp(cherry-pick)` a commit `Cfeature` from branch feature:

```
git cp Cfeature

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both modified:   src/afile.txt
```

I decide to remain src/afile.txt as that in `Cdev`. I tried
`git restore src/afile.txt`, but it failed.

Comment: Try `git restore --ours src/afile.txt`. Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt---ours

Comment: Just resolve the conflict however you like. It's easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `git checkout` to reset the file to what it was on `Cdev`:

```
git checkout Cdev src/afile.txt
```

And then continue with the `cherry-pick`:

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```